# How to get tap location when using scaleEffect

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a ZStack with an Image and a small circle, and some gestures for panning and zooming in/out on the Image.  I want the small circle to change location based on where the user taps.  Everything is working fine until I start zooming in with scaleEffect.  How can I account for the current scale value when placing the circle? (See `TODO: Fix tap point when scaled` for where the issue is.)

```
struct PodMapTest: View {

    @State var circlePosition = CGPoint.zero
    @State var position = CGSize.zero

    @State var scale: CGFloat = 1.0
    @State var lastScaleValue: CGFloat = 1.0

    @State var tapPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
    @State var dragSize: CGSize = CGSize.zero
    @State var lastDrag: CGSize = CGSize.zero

    @GestureState private var dragOffset = CGSize.zero
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            ZStack {
                Image("floorPlan")
                    .resizable()
                self.circle
            }
            .scaledToFit()
            .animation(.linear)
            .scaleEffect(self.scale)
            .offset(self.dragSize)
            .gesture(MagnificationGesture().onChanged { val in
                let delta = val / self.lastScaleValue
                self.lastScaleValue = val
                self.scale = self.scale * delta

            }.onEnded { val in
                // without this the next gesture will be broken
                self.lastScaleValue = 1.0
                }

            )
                .simultaneousGesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 1, coordinateSpace: .local).onChanged({ val in
                    print("dragging map")
                    self.tapPoint = val.startLocation
                    self.dragSize = CGSize(width: val.translation.width + self.lastDrag.width, height: val.translation.height + self.lastDrag.height)
                })
                    .onEnded({ (val) in
                        self.dragSize = CGSize(width: val.translation.width + self.lastDrag.width, height: val.translation.height + self.lastDrag.height)
                        self.lastDrag = self.dragSize
                    }))
                .simultaneousGesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local).onChanged({ (val) in


                        // TODO: Fix tap point when scaled
                        let tapPoint = CGPoint(x: val.startLocation.x - self.dragSize.width, y: val.startLocation.y - self.dragSize.height)
                        self.circlePosition = tapPoint
                }))
            Spacer()
        }
    }

    var circle: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 20, height: 20, alignment: .center)
        .position(circlePosition)
    }
}
```